# Odoo 14 enterprise POS close session error (ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'res.partner')

Tags: python, odoo, erb, odoo-14, pos

when i try to close my session and post entries for my POS,
I had this error :

Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
result = request.dispatch()
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 347, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 912, in **call**
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 531, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/opt/odoo14/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1393, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo14/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1381, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/api.py", line 396, in call_kw
result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/api.py", line 383, in _call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo14/custom_addons/bi_pos_pay_later/models/pos_session.py", line 35, in action_pos_session_closing_control
session.action_pos_session_close()
File "/opt/odoo14/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_session.py", line 295, in action_pos_session_close
return self._validate_session()
File "/opt/odoo14/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_session.py", line 311, in _validate_session
self.with_company(self.company_id)._create_account_move()
File "/opt/odoo14/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_session.py", line 408, in _create_account_move
data = self._create_invoice_receivable_lines(data)
File "/opt/odoo14/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_session.py", line 657, in _create_invoice_receivable_lines
receivable_line = MoveLine.create(vals)
File "", line 2, in create
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
return create(self, arg)
File "/opt/odoo14/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 3843, in create
lines = super(AccountMoveLine, self).create(vals_list)
File "", line 2, in create
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
return create(self, arg)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_fields.py", line 533, in create
recs = super().create(vals_list)
File "", line 2, in create
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
return create(self, arg)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/models.py", line 3868, in create
records = self._create(data_list)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/models.py", line 3974, in _create
cr.execute(query, params)
File "", line 2, in execute
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/sql_db.py", line 101, in check
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/sql_db.py", line 298, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
Exception

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'res.partner'
```

this happened  especially if some of my POS orders are invoiced ( defined with customers )  How can i solve it ?
i use odoo 14 enterprise hosted on premise.

Comment: Do you have odoo vanilla code or do you use customizations (code)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The shared error log says you use third-party modules like 'bi_pos_pay_later'. Kindly make sure that these modules are not the ones causing errors by creating a new database with these modules and checking the same workflow. If you find that the issue is with the third-party modules, kindly report the same to its developers since they will be better suited to help you.